# how to play video online with one extention and compatible with all platforms?

Tags: video

I need help to play video with one extension at all platforms, for example FLV is running under WIN but not under MAC, so I have to upload FLV and Generate an other Video file with MP4 extension using FFMPEG encoder .. 
is there any solution to play video with one extension at all platforms ?
regards.

Answer (score 0):

## You can't.

There is no one-size-fits-all video codec for ***all*** platforms.

That said, you can go for a lowest common denominator that will cover most platforms.

- h264 video
- mp3 audio
- baseline 3.0

For the most part, if you really want to distribute video to all platforms you'll need to do multiple encodings of the source video. FLV is particularly a bad choice, unless you are only interested in playing the video in Flash-based players.

*BTW: Your question would be easier to answer with more specifics if you defined the "platforms" you are targeting, the use case, codec parameters/details, etc.*